# Facebook Login security concern with the javascritp JDK

Tags: authentication, oauth, facebook

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Isn’t OAuth, OpenID, Facebook Connect, and others crazy from a security standpoint?](https://security.stackexchange.com/questions/4032/isnt-oauth-openid-facebook-connect-and-others-crazy-from-a-security-standpoi)

I have some real concerns about how to use facebook login for my wabb-app. I have a standard registration and login process through https with email(including validation link)+password. However, I want to let people use facebook to login and register with my app, and since facebook e-mail is already validated, I don't even need to validate it.

I use the javascritp JDK for the login, which is the simplest way to integrate according to [facebook](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/concepts/login/login-architecture/) and should be used for webb-apps. However this only certifies my user is logged in client side, I don't see how I can trust my client when he says he is correctly logged into facebook with X user and I hand him back the confidential data.

I have found a workaround for this issue as explained in this [question](http://facebook.stackoverflow.com/questions/13955450/facebook-authentication-via-client-sdk-security-concept), but have no true answer, and I would really like for an expert to explain why it seems so awkward to use facebook connect and if I'm truly understanding it right.

Thank you so much.

Comment: I think you need to research the oath protocol, and the concepts of federated logon more deeply. Take a look at http://security.stackexchange.com/q/13803/13909, http://security.stackexchange.com/q/4032/13909

Comment: @Daren, welcome to [security.se]. Check out the linked duplicate question - if you still have additional questions, please ask again!

Comment: WTF! I don't see how my question is identical to a debate over the advantages of OAuth protocols... I'm asking if I'm missing something about the implementation of facebook login from my app viewpoint... I asked this in security.stackexchange.com since nobody seemed to be able to anwser the same question on stackoverflow...

Comment: @Daren: The answer to your question is that you need to use OAuth on the server.  See the duplicate for details.

Comment: @SLaks: Yeah, that's what I ended up doing, facebook just got it wrong recommending the javascript SDK for webb-apps... the moment you have user info in your own server, you need server-side login. Thanks.

Comment: @Daren: Facebook is recommending the Javascript SDK for _client-side_ webapps